# What is the aftermath from Heaven's Reach?

Tags: uplift

In the final book (that I know of) the fanatic's seize of earth has just ended and the moderates will soon be in-system to help protect Earthclan.

What happens next? ('next' = next few hundred years)

I can put a few pieces of the puzzle on the table:

1) the moderates will protect Earthclan but won't support vendettas.

2) ... unless the fanatics have been a thorn in their side for a long time and they see a way to deal with them once and for all.

3) ... and/or unless the library says that that's the way near-extinctions have been handled in the past.

4) Earthclan may not be entitled to reparations since the fanatics are declared enemies.

5) ... but that depends on the rules in that universe. Earthclan got reparations in Uplift War... but we don't know the details. Maybe it was for damage to the ecosystem and interference with patron/client rights but the invasion and occupation were uncompensated.

6) Earthclan will certainly have salvage rights to all of the debris within the system. (Ditto the Tymbrimi.) No one will dare mess with them once they've reconstructed a new fleet.

7) Putting on the wolfling hat... maybe the fanatics aren't driven to extinction. *But maybe they are forcefully adopted by Earthclan and Tymbrimi* to make them better galactic citizens. To their current leadership that would be a fate worse than extinction.

I don't know if you can make a story out of this. People who are attracted to these stories usually aren't attracted to vendetta stories.  On the other hand a story about humans dealing with resentful clients might have potential.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a fanfic writing board.